# simulate TinyMCE RTL button click after toolbar is instantiated

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce, right-to-left

Is there any way to change the directionality of a textarea that is connected to a TinyMCE toolbar, by directly using the same commands that are created in plugins? What I mean is, I want to programmatically run the RTL directionality without actually clicking on the toolbar's icon.

In the source code of the `directionality` plugin, the following code is included:

```
        ed.addCommand('mceDirectionRTL', function() {
            setDir("rtl");
        });
```

This means that `mceDirectionRTL` is a command. Can I use it directly in the code? I tried but it isn't recognized.

The reason I'm asking is that I want to run this command AFTER a tinyMCE instance is started, not during the initialization/setup function of the TinyMCE toolbar. I have a bunch of texraeas, some are english and some have the class `ar` to denote they are for Arabic, which is RTL.

But when I do this:
`$('ID of my textarea'_ifr').contents().find('body').attr('dir', 'rtl');`

Then everything is fine except that the `mceExternalToolbar` (the whole toolbar!) not just the textarea, becomes rtl. So the external toolbar basically goes out of place, and leans to the right side of the page. But I only want the textarea that it is connected to to have RTL text, not the whole toolbar!

So I want to somehow externally simulate clicking the RTL button on the toolbar AFTER the toolbar is instantiated. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set and redraw may be a solution:

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=9735

```
tinyMCE.settings['directionality'] = 'rtl';
tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceRemoveControl', false, 'editor );
tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', false, 'editor );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you "install" the directionality plugin you can do something like this. You also need the reference to tinyMCE.

```
function(directionality){
    var command = directionality == 'ltr' ? 'mceDirectionLTR' : 'mceDirectionRTL'
    for(var i = 0; i++; i<tinyMCE.editors.length;{
    tinyMCE.editors[i].execCommand(command)
    }
}
```

I have two editors on my site. It seems to get the job done for me.

Answer (score 0):

No need to build a new plugin

1. Use the `directionality` plugin
2. Then add rtl & ltr buttons to `toolbar`

```
      options:{
          selector: '#editor1',
          height: 350,
          language: 'fa_IR',
          plugins: 'directionality',
          toolbar: 'rtl ltr',
      }
```

[image: sample output]